# use of JavaScript scrollIntoView results in an obscured element

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I am testing a Web App using Java , Selenium & TestNG.

I am trying to click an element referenced only by a placeholder that opens a popup.

I have to scroll to the element to bring it into view.

This is the scrolling code:

```
public static boolean scrollIntoView(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    debug.print(thisClass + " scroll into view...");
    int attempts = 0;
    while (attempts < 2) {
        try {
            // Create instance of Javascript executor
            JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            // now execute query which actually will scroll until that element has appeared
            je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
            debug.print(thisClass + " scrolled into view!");
            return true;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            // expected
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int errorCode = 1520008991;
            System.err.println(thisClass + " Error Code: " + errorCode + " error in scrollIntoView: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is my code to find & click the element

```
// identifier = text used to identify placeholder
public static boolean findXpathPlaceholderAndClick(WebDriver driver, String identifier) {
    printLine();
    myPrint(thisClass + " findXpathPlaceholderAndClick. ");
    myPrint(thisClass + " Find placeholder using identifier: " + identifier);
    List<WebElement> placeholders = driver
            .findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class, 'label-placeholder-text')]"));

    myPrint(thisClass + " placeholders count: " + placeholders.size());
    for (WebElement element : placeholders) {
        // select an element
        if(!element.isDisplayed()) {
            Common.scrollIntoView(element, driver);
        }
        String text = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        myPrint(thisClass + " text: " + text);
        if (text.contains(identifier)) {
            myPrint(thisClass + " found " + text);
            String forId = element.getAttribute("for");
            myPrint(thisClass + " id of input field = " + forId);
            WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.id(forId));
            if (!inputField.isDisplayed()) {
                return false;
            }
            try {
                inputField.click();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                int errorCode = 1523444596;
                System.err.println(thisClass + " error Code: " + errorCode + " Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the HTML of the actual element I am trying to click on:

```
<div class="form-group label-placeholder">
    <input class="form-control text-ellipsis-global" id="gwt-uid-2401" data-empty="false" style="" type="text"> 
    <label class="label-placeholder-text" for="gwt-uid-2401">Geometry Required</label> 
    <label class="label-placeholder-icon" for="gwt-uid-2401" style="display: block;"> <i class="icon-display-list"></i> </label>
</div>
```

Finally, this is the output to my log:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
utils.Common                                         findXpathPlaceholderAndClick. 
utils.Common                                         Find placeholder using identifier: Geometry Required
utils.Common                                         placeholders count: 6
utils.Common                                         text: Design name
utils.Common                                         text: Icon
utils.Common                                         text: Colour
utils.Common                                         text: Reference To
utils.Common                                         scroll into view...
utils.Common                                         scrolled into view!
utils.Common                                         text: Network
utils.Common                                         scroll into view...
utils.Common                                         scrolled into view!
utils.Common                                         text: Geometry Required
utils.Common                                         found Geometry Required
utils.Common                                         id of input field = gwt-uid-2401
tests.designer.CreateAssetDesignTest                 *** click Geometry Required failed ***
tests.designer.CreateAssetDesignTest                 ASSERT:  click Geometry Required?  false

utils.Common                                         Generating screenshot. 
utils.Common                                         error Code: 1523444596 Exception: Element <input id="gwt-uid-2401" class="form-control text-ellipsis-global" type="text"> is not clickable at point (150,85) because another element <button class="gwt-Button form-control btn back-button ripple-container" type="button"> obscures it
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'SSTAPLE', ip: '172.16.190.147', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 59.0.3, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 23160, moz:profile: C:\Users\SStaple\AppData\Lo..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 18bdbb72-a68a-49d7-a7d2-9dc00f455546
```

So, it is finding the element OK, & trying to click it, but finding that element obscured by a static element.

I am pretty certain the scrolling is the problem.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: If you look at the error message, it states which element is blocking the click. You will need to investigate what the blocking element is and how to get rid of it, etc. In my experience, it's typically some popup, etc. that you need to dismiss or just wait for it to disappear but I can't see the site so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Does your page have a floating header or footer?  If so, you may need to consider waiting for them to animate, and potentially offset your scroll to compensate.

Also, do you use actions at all?  It may be that your virtual mouse pointer is activating a hover menu as you scroll?

In either case, running your test with a debugger and stepping through slowly may demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, I can see the object blocking the link. It is on a top bar that does not move. The object I am after is still visible on the screenshot generated.

Comment: Thanks @HarryKing - replacing my input.click with actions.moveToElement(inputField).click().build().perform(); improved my hit rate!